# Drawing lags in Android drawing application with canvas

Tags: android, performance, canvas, arraylist, navigation-drawer

I am building an drawing application in Android using canvas. I'm directly painting on the canvas without using the offline bitmap/canvas. Everything works fine on a 512M memory device but on slower devices, the application lags after a few strokes. The application allows user to put some cliparts, background and flood fill, too.

For all this different objects I am using a ArrayList with a bean class to store each paint object, its style and its bitmap.

In onDraw(), each time I am iterating over this ArrayList and draw everything that is stored in that ArrayList. I am providing undo and redo so cannot use drawingCache.

In short, I need to improve overall performance of the application. How can I achieve that? Is the application structure proper or anything that I should change? I can post some code if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a temp Bitmap keeping some of your drawing,  for example each 32 strokes,  so you need one drawBitmap and at most 31 direct drawing calls,  when you need an undo you can rebuild your Bitmap,  note you still need to keep your ArrayList for undo to work properly

Comment: Thanks @pskink for your answer. I'll try out the method you suggested. Just wanted to know, the ArrayList method is proper or not. Again, thanks for the valuable answer. Can I ask another question related to zooming in same application here or start a new thread?

Comment: 1. list is ok 2. new thread

Comment: @pskink There is a problem implementing your suggestion. I forgot to mention I am allowing users to move the objects around in canvas. If I'll use bitmap then they will not be moveable.